# Github is very slow and I have to open links in a new tab

Tags: github

Recently Github has been incredibly slow for me.  I click a link and nothing happens. I wait and wait... but I can right click and open any link in a new tab fairly quickly.  Directly clicking never seems to work, or at least not consistently.

At first I thought it might be an extension, but I've tried it without any enabled and it still behaves the same way. Is anyone else experiencing this?

[image: slow-github.gif]

Comment: Troubleshooting issues like this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I want to add an update that is cause of this was the **iCloud Password manager browser extension**! This is apparently a known issue as documented in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/15dqbkf/icloud_password_on_google_chrome_slows_down/) - My solution was to remove the browser extension (I switched to BitWarden)

Answer (score -2):

GitHub works fine on my side. Try with a different connection and a different device.

You can otherwise check GitHub status on a few websites, e.g.:

- https://downdetector.com/status/github/
- https://www.githubstatus.com/
- https://twitter.com/githubstatus